# Try to run sbt shell gives me error server failed to start error 5

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, sbt

I was following the tutorial for build an scalable websocket app in Heroku, following the tutorial [Writing Scalable WebSocket Applications on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced) and trying to set up Play Framework to work on Eclipse IDE, downloaded play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial from Play Framework site, added sbt-plugin annotation in plugins.sbt file, git bashed from project folder and tried the command sbt, it gives me, following error and I can't proceed with compile command:

```
 server failed to start on local:sbt-server-cc02d04ca19b451f676c. java.io.IOException: Could 
 not create lock for \\.\pipe\sbt-server-cc02d04ca19b451f676c_lock, error 5
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with Heroku. Please don't tag spam.

Comment: @Chris https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced

Comment: That doesn't make it a Heroku question.

Comment: Your sbt compile server might be locked probably running another process. try finding out what your sbt is doing. (in Mac/Linux using `ps - ef | grep sbt' would to the work).